# React bootstrap vertically centerized

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, centering

I want to centerize my form verticaly and horizantaly use react-bootstrap.

React code:

```
 <Container>
  <Row  >
    <Col  md={{ span: 4, offset: 4 }}>
      <Form onSubmit={(e) => loginHandler(e)}>
        <Form.Group controlId='formGroupEmail'>
          <Form.Label>Kullanıcı Adı veya Email Adresi</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type='email' placeholder='Enter email' />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group controlId='formGroupPassword'>
          <Form.Label>Şifre</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type='password' placeholder='Password' />
        </Form.Group>
        <Button type='submit'>Giriş Yap</Button>
      </Form>
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
```

I centerize horizontally using  md={{ span: 4, offset: 4 }} in my Col conponent but I cant verticaly centerized.

Comment: you can try this `<Row  style = {{alignItems: 'center', height:'100vh', display: 'flex'}}>`

Answer (score 0):

If you use React Css, you can try "align-middle" class in your Row component.